# When a mother travels with baby (2 years) without father, what documents she needs to have for baby?

Tags: air-travel, usa, children, paperwork

My wife wants to travel to another country for one month and would like to take our baby with her. We currently live in the USA, but are originally from Ukraine. The baby has a child travel document with a valid USA visa.

Question: Does my wife need to have any additional documents for the baby so she can travel without the father? In Ukraine we would need a written agreement from the father to allow my wife to fly with the baby, but what about in the USA?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm sure that this has been asked here but I can't find the answer.

The general rule for children traveling in the company of one parent is that the second parent needs to provide a notarized letter that he or she is not opposed to the other parent to be traveling with the child.

I have provided this letter multiple times when my son traveled with my wife to Ukraine and Israel.

You can see relevant policy from your airline but here is the [American Airline](http://www.aa.com/i18n/travelInformation/specialAssistance/childrenTraveling.jsp#IdentificationRequirements) policy page and [Sample Letter](http://photos.state.gov/libraries/unitedkingdom/164203/cons-acs/sample_letter_of_consent_to_travel.pdf) as required by the State Department

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! I have another question: to get this letter, do I need to have translated birth certificate of the baby? Is it possible to translate this certificate in USA? Thanks!

Comment: @Vitaliy You will need a document that will allow you to establish identity for your child.  Translation is possible but need to be notarized.

Comment: It gets asked (and answered) quite frequently, but with different details because the question is usually about travel from one specific country to another.  If you search for "travel consent letter" you'll find some helpful examples.